# How to import woocommerce custom fields data into another site?

Tags: php, plugin-development, woocommerce-offtopic, mysql, bulk-import

I m trying to import this product custom field data into my another wordpress site but its not showing any option to me when i try to import it into my other site ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: isnt there anyone to answer this question?

Comment: I don't know WooCommerce well enough, but I'm not completely sure what's happening here. On one site you have a custom field 'Store' - is this added by a plugin or by configuration in WooCommerce? (If it's configuration, do you know where that is stored?) Can you verify the configuration or plugin are replicated to the new site by the import process? Which CSV importer are you using - does WooCommerce provide that too? Where does it get its field list from? Can you debug why it's not finding your Store field?